# Can a socket.io server communicate with a non-socket.io client

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am building a chat server which uses a custom protocol for communicating with clients over sockets. The client sends specific strings to the server and the server must take an appropriate action based on these non-standard messages. I can't change this protocol, nor do I have any access to the underlying client code.

My question is, can I use the node.js socket.io package to power the server socket communication if I have no idea how the client is handling it's socket activity? I'm asking because, reading through the socket.io docs, each time I push anything through a socket an 'event' is associated with each action.

Is it possible to send a very exact message to the client from the server with this 'event' bundled in? Am I better off using the websockets package?

Comment: I know it's not the specific technology you're asking about, but you might look into WebRTC solutions - you'll even find node.js chat server tutorials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can a socket.io server communicate with a non-socket.io client

No.  A socket.io server requires both the webSocket protocol for connection initiation and the socket.io format on top of that.  So, a socket.io server can only talk to a socket.io client and vice versa.

If your chat client uses a custom protocol, then you need to implement a TCP server that also speaks that custom protocol (whatever it is).

If you can modify the client, then you can modify it to use a socket.io client and then you can send your chat messages via socket.io where your socket.io server can then receive those messages.

> The client sends specific strings to the server and the server must take an appropriate action based on these non-standard messages. I can't change this protocol, nor do I have any access to the underlying client code.

Then, you have to implement a server that speaks your custom client protocol based on whatever the underlying protocol is for the client.  There is no other way around it.

> I'm asking because, reading through the socket.io docs, each time I push anything through a socket an 'event' is associated with each action.

This is how the socket.io layer works.  It sends a message and (optional) data.  This can always be used to just send data by just declaring a generic `data` message and then just listening for the `data` message on the other end.  But, this assumes you can modify both client and server to work this way.  If you can't modify your client to use the socket.io protocol, then you can't use socket.io.

Comment: Thank you, very decisive answer. Could you point me in the direction of a library I could use to implement a purely TCP based server with my own protocol? I'm thinking 'net' from first glances